# Minifie style.php in head of index.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i currently have an wordpress theme options page. I read all the theme options styles in style.php which i then include in the head of my website.

Does anyone know how to minify this style.php file?

most of the "on-the-fly" scripts offer an solution, but it changes the header which results in an error message "headers already sent".

header.php:

```
<style>
    <?php require_once('css/style.php');?>
</style>
```

style.php:

```
<?php
?>
body {
    background-color:<?php global $variable; echo $variable['color-background'];?>;
    font-family:<?php global $variable; echo $variable['typography6']['font-family'];?>;
}

a {
    color: <?php global $variable; echo $variable['link-color']['regular'];?>;
}

<?php

?>
```

does anyone have a solution?

Comment: you're trying to remove spaces,newlines ,etc right?

Comment: yes, there should be no whitespace at all.

Comment: You do not need the `<?php`-blocks at the beginnend and the end of your file. and I think, `global $variable;` could be ommitted, too.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [CssMin](https://code.google.com/p/cssmin/)-project. It's a PHP-class that helps you with this.